# Where is basic auth credentials stored in the browser?

Tags: cookies, basic-authentication

Where is basic authentication credentials stored in the browser?

They are sent as an 'Authorization' header on each request (with base64 encoded value).

But where are these values stored on the browser? They don't appear to be in cookies / sessions etc..

Comment: I have been checking for some time and I do not think it is visible to the user. They are not stored in the regular cache cause even when I disable cache on my browser, clear site data and run in incognito mode the basic authentication credentials are still reused during that session in all browser tabs on that window (meaning I don't have to type it again).